# Is there any risk setting Wordpress file permissions and FS method to 'direct' on localhost?

Tags: php, security

After installing a fresh WordPress on my computer using XAMPP, I got this message when I tried uploading a theme:

> Connection Information
> To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.

I added the code

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

to the config.php file for it to upload without asking for any ftp credentials.

Can I leave define('FS_METHOD', 'direct') in the config.php file forever?